# MVC, .NET 5.0 - How to filter Index/Create pages based on database value?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC app using EF Core on .NET 5.0. I have configured my application's Startup.CS file to implement Azure AD Authentication per this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

And in my `Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file, I can access/display my user's e-mail address with:

```
<span>Signed in as: @User.Identity.Name</span>
```

I have a table called "Users" in my SQL Server database that associates an OrganizationID with each user's e-mail address. Possible values are 1, 2, and 3 for Organizations 1, 2, and 3 and then value 99 is an Administrator who should have access to everything from Organizations 1, 2, and 3. For the visual effect the "Users" table/model , it looks like:

```
+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| UserID | EmailAddress    | OrganizationID |
+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| 1      | User1@email.com | 1              |
+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| 2      | User2@email.com | 2              |
+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| 3      | User3@email.com | 3              |
+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| 4      | Admin@email.com | 99             |
+--------+-----------------+----------------+
```

I have another table/model that has records related to OrganizationID, let's call it "Courses":

```
+----------+------------+----------------+
| CourseID | CourseName | OrganizationID |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 1        | Math       | 1              |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 2        | Science    | 1              |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 3        | Art        | 2              |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 4        | Literature | 3              |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

When I scaffold the CRUD pages for "Courses" - when a user goes to the Index page, I only want them to see Courses for their own OrganizationID. If they are an Administrator, I want them to see all Courses.

When users go to the "Courses" Create page, I want the drop-down list for Organization to default to their own OrganizationID (and to be unchangeable) unless they are an Administrator, in which case I want for them to be able to manually select the OrganizationID.

I think this is handled in the controller for each page/Action? But I don't know how to access the OrganizationID based on their user's e-mail address and I don't know how to modify my controller to do so. After scaffolding CRUD pages, the controller for the "Courses" Index page looks like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var context_variable = _context.FormPage.Include(n => n.OrganizationNavigation);
            return View(await context_variable.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Is this where I modify the Index to filter certain records? How about for the Create page?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, you can filter within your controller action method.

Longer answer: In your controller, you may be able to create an `IEnumerable<Record>` that can be sent to your View to be used in a dropdown HTML object. Something like

**Model**

Create a model that has an `IEnumerable<Record>` property. Pass this to your View as part of your object. For example, you may create a `ViewModel` class:

```
public class UserRecordsViewModel
{
  public IdentityUser AppUSer {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<Record> Records {get; set;}
}
```

If you didn't want to create a separate class for your `ViewModel`, you could just extend your `AppUser` model to have the `Records` property.

**Controller**

Populate this `ViewModel` property in your controller:

```
    var viewModel = new UserRecordsViewModel();
    viewModel.AppUser = user;
    // if admin, return all records
    if(user.OrganizationID == 99
    {
      IEnumerable<Record> viewModel.Records = repository.Records();
    }
    // if not admin, return just the records for their org
    else
    {
      IEnumerable<Record> viewModel.Records = repository.Records.Where(r => r.OrgranizationID == 
      user.OrganizationID)
    }
```

**View**

Then in your View, use the `IEnumerable<Record> Records` property to generate a dropdown. Note this assumes your `Record` object has a `Name` property:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select asp-for="Record" class="form-control">
    @foreach (var record in Model.Records)
    {
      <option value="@Name">
        @Name
      </option>
    }
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to implement your suggestion in to my app. I'm going to edit the question to name things more specifically.

Comment: Also - there are several other models that need this type of filtering, so I would prefer to be able to modify the "Users" model to include any properties that I need to instead of creating ViewModels for every combination of "Other Model" and "Users" model

Comment: @Jake regarding not using a ViewModel, you can just extend your User class directly. The same goes with other classes that need filtering. If you don't want the property to be persistent, mark it as `[NotMapped]`, although using a `ViewModel` is probably better practice. The same basic process holds: 1) add an `IEnumerable<>` property to your class, 2) populate/filter this property within your controller and pass it to the View, 3) Iterate over the items in the `IEnumberable<>` property within your View to populate the dropdown

Comment: If I go the route of using ViewModels, in the second line of code (viewModel.AppUser = user;) where is "user" defined?

Comment: @Jake if you are using MS Identity, you would set up a `UserManager<AppUser>` instance  and use something like `var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn613290(v=vs.108)

Comment: Note in my comment above, I'm using `AppUser` which has extended the `IdentityUser` base class. If you are just using the base class, it would just be `UserManager<IdentityUser>`